# как починить? pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Кто знает, почему после 10-15 минут бездействия бот умирает и выдает эту ошибку ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: вы пробовали запускать без `while`? просто `bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)`. использую данный способ с самого первого проекта (PyCharm) проблемы были только при блокировке TG в РФ, но обходились через `apihelper` и успешно работали

Comment: без интервала запускал, 15-20 минут и все, дальше переподключение выдает ошибку

Comment: @d-violet а Вы знаете что в методе `polling()` `interval` и `timeout` уже с параметрами по умолчанию 0 и 20? я вот подумал, раз 20 минут возможно что из за этого я и не могу после этих 20 минут и написать своему боту. Если правильно думаю(

Comment: попробовать вместо всего этого
`bot.infinity_polling(True)`

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы ваш бот не падал с ошибкой, используйте bot.infinity_polling() вместо bot.polling(none_stop=True), тогда хоть и будет показывать ошибку о проблемах, но бот будет работать не смотря на это

```
import telebot 

bot = telebot. TeleBot('ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗЫВАЕТЕ ВАШ BOT API токен')

@bot.massage_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_massage(message.chat.id, message.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.infinity_polling()
```

Удачи!